# Host MassTransit on docker for Linux environment

Tags: docker, masstransit

I want to setup environment for MassTransit in docker for linux, I can get    RabbitMq for docker in linux with this link https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/ , do we have any image for MassTransit in docker for linux hosting? if not how to create an image for linux.

Comment: I believe MassTransit is just a wrapper (class library) which abstracts away the complexities involved in message communication. It internally interacts with RabbitMQ or Azure Service Bus so if you have to switch underlying messaging system you will require minimum or no code updates.
In your scenario once you have the RabbitMQ setup on docker you can use MassTransit library pointing to docker RabbitMQ installation via connectionstring. 
[http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/understand/key-ideas.html]

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit is a library that you use in your application. You can run your app as a container if you wish. There are a number of guidelines on how to make the .NET Core app to run in Docker. There is nothing special in regards to MassTransit compared to any other library for .NET.